# Datastore API version

Tags: api, google-app-engine, low-level

This Dart appengine package refers two protocol buffers API versions - V3 and V4
https://github.com/dart-lang/appengine/tree/master/lib/src/protobuf_api/internal
(see also
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/)

(The public API of this Dart package forwards only to V3)

I made several attempts to find background information about the differences.

Are there suggestions how to migrate from v3 to v4?
Can v4 already be used?
Are there criterias which makes v3 a better fit than v4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- V3 seems to be used only inside AppEngine
- V4 seems to be the protocol used by the Google Cloud Datastore service.
- V1 is very similar to V4 and seems to be the successor of V3 and V4 for both AppEngine and Google Cloud Datastore.